# Variable won't be set inside the fetch function

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, var, assign

I am trying to print text content of login.php into the screen via "var result", but the fetch function won't alter value of "var result". How can I set value of result from output of the fetch function?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import Form from '../components/Form';
import loginapi from '../apis/loginapi';

var result='noresult';

export default class Login extends Component<{}>  {
 render() {
  login();
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <Logo/>
    <Form/>
    <Text>
       {result}
    </Text>
    <Text>
    </Text></View>
  );
 }
}

function login() {
  result = fetch('https://www.skateandstrike.com/loginsv/login.php').then((text) => {return text;});
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    backgroundColor:'#f05545',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  }
});


function myFunction() {
 
 this.setState({ showLoading: false });
}
```

This is not working too, using setState:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import Form from '../components/Form';
import loginapi from '../apis/loginapi';

export default class Login extends Component<{}>  {
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state = {
   data:'NoData',
  }
 }

 render() {
  login();
  return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <Logo/>
    <Form/>
     <Text>
        {this.state.data}
     </Text>
   </View>
  );
 }
}

function login() {
  fetch('https://www.skateandstrike.com/loginsv/login.php').then(data => this.setState(data));
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    backgroundColor:'#f05545',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  }
});


function myFunction() {
 
 this.setState({ showLoading: false });
}
```

Am I using setState in a wrong way? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not use `state` but global variables?

Comment: I am a newbie so have no idea about difference.

Comment: I suggest to read react-native documents, at least all fundamental sections before ask in StackOverflow. (not my downvote btw) https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html

Answer (score 1):

When using the fetch API, I'd recommend using a promise, and you parse it if you are setting the state.

React re-renders on state/props change.

sample code:

```
fetch(url)
.then(data => data.json()) // if needed
.then(data => this.setState(data))
```

remember to set state in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much but I couldn't do with this too. I added new code to my question. Could you please check it out to see if there is something wrong?